# JSF Confirm-Link using E-Mail

Tags: jsf-2

I want my Users to click on a Link sent by E-Mail to the E-Mail address 
they registered with.

How can i implement such a e-mail confirmation in jsf?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have already the code to send an e-mail, you can create a jsf site like `activeuser.xhtml?id=` and add the userid as hash. The hash should also be saved in the database. When the user opens the page you call a method with `f:event`:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{userController.idHash}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{userController.activate}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

On the page load the method `userController#activate()` gets called and you can activate the user with the given id hash and redirect to the start page.